# Adding a view on runtime to a ViewFlippers

Tags: android

I have defined two views `ExampleView1`, `ExampleView2`, `ExampleView3` and `ExampleView4` in resources.

In my Activity I have an empty ViewFlipper. Based on doing some logic I want to add either  `ExampleView1` and `ExampleView2` to the ViewFlipper and show the view.

Later I want to add based on internal logic either `ExampleView3` and `ExampleView4`.

How do I do this? Is there some tutorial or can someone help me with example code?

Answer (score 4):

Just use the [`addView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) method, which [`ViewFlipper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) inherits from [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). If your views are custom ones, you will have something like this:

```
flipper.addView(new ExampleView1());
```

On the other hand, if the views are defined inside an XML layout, you will have to inflate them first:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_view, null);
flipper.addView(view);
```

Comment: When I use a custom view the view wants to have an AttributeSet. What AttributeSet do I have to pass?